# Kill only a subprocess created by python on CMD

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, terminal, aria2

I have made a **python** script which downloads using **aria2** downloader by running a shell command which can work on Windows and Linux.

```
os.system("aria2c " + url + options)
#some code I want to run if the process is stopped
```

Now, I want to test my program for the situation when file could not be downloaded. So, after executing the 'python downloader.py' on command-prompt (cmd.exe) Windows, I press **Ctrl+C** to stop only the download ('**aria2c.exe**' process only) but keep running my python code.

Doing this on **Ubuntu** *terminal* works fine! But on **cmd** windows, **Ctrl+C** stops '**aria2c.exe**' process but also stops my python code. I want to know I can achieve this on command prompt?

If you need to know, this is what shows up on cmd:

```
    File "downloader.py", line 106, in download
      os.system(myCommand)
Keyboard interrupt
```

Comment: On Win, if you know the image name (aria2c.exe) you can use: taskkill /f /im aria2c.exe.  This will kill the task and can be run via subprocess or directly in cmd.  Is this something like what you’re after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could catch the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception, then execute the code you want to afterward.

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        os.system("aria2c " + url + options)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Keyboard Interrupt Detected')
            # the rest of your code
            pass
```

Comment: What does the value of __name__ actually means?

Comment: It is a special variable that represents the context the script is running in. If it is the main script (i.e., being invoked as the top-level script `python your-top-level-script-name.py`), then this will run. It's a best practice because sometimes when you import a script, you dont want some code to run. That code you dont want to run should be in a block like above

Answer (score 1):

This code will open your EXE in the separate command prompt if your os is windows.

```
import os

if os.name == 'nt':
 os.system("start /wait cmd /c aria2c " + url + options)
else
 os.system("aria2c " + url + options)
```

Comment: You mean all windows operating system have the name after windows 'nt'? And will this open a seperate command prompt window?

Comment: yes, it should be. 'nt' is the value for windows and it opens a separate window.